# JSON file on instagram __a=1 give me html?

Tags: php, json, instagram

I want to point out that I started studying php this week, so the code will be a bit of shit, but for now it's enough that it works sincerely

I created this script that going to https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?__a=1 (there is a JSON file at this address) using file_get_contents () of that URL, should return the JSON file to me , and locally this happens! locally works perfectly!
but hosting on my domain the script doesn't work correctly, that is file_get_contents () gives me back a strange html page, which is absolutely NOT found in the link I gave it! and I don't understand why and what is due!
instagram notices that i have read the data and redirects me to another page? did I miss something in the code? am I doing it the wrong way? I have no idea, I ask you for help!
I also tried to read the file which is also located at cURL but nothing to do

I also thought of redoing all the code in JS, hoping that the same thing would not happen, but I would not like to do it all over again and maybe find myself with a code that gives me the same result!

I attach the code here

```
<?php

$commentiPost;
$likePost;
$postData;
$image;
$urlprofilo;
$followers;
$username;
$follow;
$like;
$commenti;

function getMediaByUsername($count) {
global $image;
global $commentiPost;
global $likePost;
global $urlprofilo;
global $followers;
global $username;
global $follow;
global $postData;
global $like;
global $commenti;
$uname      = htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]);
$username   = strtolower(str_replace(' ','_',$uname));
$url        = "https://www.instagram.com/".$username."/?__a=1";

$userinfo   = file_get_contents($url);
$userdata   = json_decode($userinfo,true);
$user       = $userdata['graphql']['user'];
$iteration_url = $url;



if(!empty($user)){

    $followers  = $user['edge_followed_by']['count'];
    $follow     = $user['edge_follow']['count'];
    $fullname   = $user['full_name'];
    $username   = $user['username'];
    $profilepic = $user['profile_pic_url'];
$profilepic = (explode("/",$profilepic));
$urlprofilo = "https://scontent-frt3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/$profilepic[6]";


$limit      = $count;
$tryNext    = true;
$found      = 0;


while ($tryNext) {
    $tryNext = false;

    $remote = file_get_contents( $iteration_url );

    $response = $remote;

    if ($response === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $data = json_decode($response, true);

    if ( $data === null) {
        return false;
    }
    $media = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media'];

    foreach ( $media['edges'] as $index => $node ) {
        if ( $found + $index < $limit ) {
            if (isset($node['node']['is_video']) && $node['node']['is_video'] == true) {
                $type = 'video';
            } else {
                $type = 'image';
            }
                $like = $like + $node['node']['edge_liked_by']['count'];
    $commenti = $commenti + $node['node']['edge_media_to_comment']['count'];
                $image[] = array( "<a href=".$node['node']['display_url'].">
                                <img src=".$node['node']['display_url']." alt="." />
                                <h3>Like: </strong>".$node['node']['edge_liked_by']['count']."</strong>    Commenti: <strong>".$node['node']['edge_media_to_comment']['count']."</strong></h3>
                            </a>");
                $postData[] = array(" '".gmdate("d-m-Y",$node['node']['taken_at_timestamp'])."',");
              $likePost[] = array(" ".$node['node']['edge_liked_by']['count'].",");
            $commentiPost[] = array(" ".$node['node']['edge_media_to_comment']['count'].",");

        }
    }

    $found += count($media['edges']);


    if ( $media['page_info']['has_next_page'] && $found < $limit ) {
        $iteration_url = $url . '&max_id=' . $media['page_info']['end_cursor'];
        $tryNext = true;
    }
}






} else{




}

}
getMediaByUsername( 12);

if(isset($image))
{
   $postTot = count($image);
}
else {
    $postTot = 0;
}
if($postTot > 0 and $followers > 0){
$ER = round(((($like + $commenti)/$postTot)/$followers)*100, 1);
}
else {
    $ER = 0;
}




?>
```

Comment: Where are you hosting?  I noticed exactly same thing. My nodeJS app http request worked like a charm and still works on my local dev env but when publishing my code to AWS Cloud, the response is HTML saying "Sorry, this page isn't availabe".